# unable to send mail using Mutt

Tags: linux, rhel, mutt

Recently we have migrated Unix OS to new flavor. Since then we couldn't able to send mails. I think we are missing some configuration, Could someone help in resolving the issue.

```
Command: echo "" | mutt -s "subject" -i /tmp/test.txt -a /tmp/test.txt xxx@gmail.com

Error: Can't stat xxx@gmail.com: No such file or directory
       xxx@gmail.com: unable to attach file.
```

**Current OS: Oracle Linux Server release 7.1**

**Mutt 1.5.21 (2010-09-15)**

Please let me know what would be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mutt). It states, that `-a` takes a list of arguments, which need to be terminated by `--`.

Comment: Thank you. '-a' is for attachments, but what I observed is without attachments also I am unable to send mail.

Comment: Sorry. I am not sure how can I check that.

Comment: I just checked and I got this. **imsimta version**. If you are asking me to check this. Then I checked and I got the below exception.  `If 'imsimta' is not a typo you can run the following command to lookup the package that contains the binary:
    command-not-found imsimta`

Comment: Contact your system administrator, if you do not know your MTA.

Comment: Thanks Ceving, I have used nail application which mailx. Working very fine. Thanks for your help.